# Printing to different labels using a loop

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, label

if I have an array of 10 items and 10 UILabels named say animals = cat,dog,elephant,mouse,moose etc

And 10 labels named

Label1 , label2 etc

Is it possible to use a loop to print the items into the 10 labels i.e

I won't make an example because I'll just confuse it I think ..

Thanks

Comment: you need to put the labels in an array, so you can do a loop with it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have array of items and another one of labels then

```
zip(labels,items).forEach {  $0.text = $1 }
```

or

```
labels.indices?.forEach { labels[$0].text = items[$0] }
```